# Why Is powershell unable to find this item?

Tags: powershell

Using this command `Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -like '*advanced*'}` the shell is able to locate the item.

```
    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer


Name                           Property
----                           --------
Advanced                       Start_SearchFiles   : 2
                               ServerAdminUI       : 0
                               Hidden              : 2
...continues...
```

But if I try any other variation

```
Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -eq 'Advanced'}
Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -contains 'Advanced'}
Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -contains '*adv*'}
```

They all come up empty. As far as I can tell, it should be getting the same result, no?

Comment: `-contains` looks for an element in an array of elements. And this element has to be a perfect match. So in this case it's expected behaviour. For the registry provider the name of a registry key is actually the complete path. That's why the version with the `-eq` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the bottom:

```
Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -contains 'Advanced'}
Get-ChildItem | where-object {$_.Name -contains '*adv*'}
```

These won't work because `-contains` is a [**containment operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators), and *not* a **string comparison** operator.

`-contains` expects *a collection* of some sort (like an array for example), and then tests whether the right-hand operand (`'Advanced'` or `'*adv*'`) is present in the collection.

If you have a scalar (a single non-collection object) on the left-hand side of `-contains`, it's equivalent to `-eq` - and as you've found, `-eq` doesn't yield the desired result either.

#### So, why *doesn't* `-eq` work?

The reason is that the `Name` property of the items in the `Registry` provider consists of *the full key path*. PowerShell's formatting subsystem takes care of trimming the `Name` value when presented in the Shell, which is why it *looks like* it might just be `Advanced`. Resolve it's value directly, however, reveals the full name:

```
$AdvancedKey = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*advanced*'} |Select -First 1
$AdvancedKey.Name 
# shows HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

---

### How to search registry keys by exact name then?!

Fear not! The `Registry` provider attaches the non-rooted key name as a hidden property named `PSChild` which you can use in downstream commands:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq 'Advanced'}
```

Additionally, the provider cmdlets also translates the name argument for you automatically, so you could have simply done:

```
Get-Item Advanced
# or 
Get-Item *adv*
```

Comment: @drag_me_under you're welcome, happy it helped! I also just upvoted your question, you should have enough rep to upvote yourself now :)